# Rendering a different view after the user is logged In

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a web application in MVC 4. How do we create a different view and render it based on if user is logged in or not? I am not sure if I am asking the right question since I am new to programming. I have looked this online but haven't found any resource that guides a beginner to do it. I'm pretty sure this is done in the controller but my question is how to tell the controller to render a different view after checking that the user is logged in. However, if there is some other obvious and efficient way of doing this then I would greatly appreciate if someone took the time to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Forms Authentication.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class LogIN
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public class LogInRepository 
    {


        public bool CheckUser(string UserName, string Password)
        {

          //Query the database here and return true or false depending on the username and the password
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult LogOn(LogIN model, string returnUrl)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               LogInRepository rep = new LogInRepository();
               string UserRole = string.Empty;
               if (rep.CheckUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
               {
                  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName);


                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                       return Redirect(returnUrl);
                   else
                       return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);

               }
               else
               {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
               }

           }

           // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
           return View(model);
       }
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account LogIn</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

**Web.config settings:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Test/LogOn" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Test/Index" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

If the User is not logged on user will be redirected to LogOn view and if logged in will redirect to Index view.

Answer (score 1):

there's an override when you do `return View()`

```
return View("myView", myModel");
```

for example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return View("GoodUser");

    return View("BadUser");
}
```

But if you're new, I would suggest 2 things:

- see the hole online curse that is available for free in http://www.asp.net/mvc (right side where it says "Essential Videos")
- create an MVC3 project and see how they do it as it's comes already with Membership

Comment: thank you very much. I've started looking at the videos you told me to look at.